# Strange behaviour of `timer_settime()`

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm trying to set Linux timer so that I get signal each 0.1 seconds (infinitely). I have problem with `timer_settime()` call. Surprisingly this code seems to work:

```
#define Msec 1e6
#define Cycle 100 * Msec

//...

#define SIGNO SIGRTMIN
struct sigaction sa = { .sa_handler = &each_cycle };
sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);

timer_t timer;
struct sigevent te = {
    .sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL,
    .sigev_signo = SIGNO,
    .sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timer
};

/* I don't know why this setting works. */
struct itimerspec it = {
    .it_interval.tv_nsec = Cycle,
    .it_value.tv_nsec = Cycle
};

if (sigaction (SIGNO, &sa, NULL) < 0 ||
    timer_create (CLOCK_REALTIME, &te, &timer) != 0 ||
    timer_settime (timer, 0, &it, 0) != 0
 ) {

    fprintf (stderr, "Unable to register timer.");
    return 1;
}
```

Surprising because according to my understaning it should cause expiring of timer after one time. Before I was trying `.it_value.tv_sec = INT32_MAX` — this seems to be most reasonable, because `.it_value = {0,0}` disarms timer.
Unfortunatelly setting tv_sec to any value results in no signal. I'm running Arch Linux on Raspberry Pi 3 (GCC7), I've tried to remove optimization, no change.

Comment: The way I read the manual page for timer_settime, it does as expected: "If this field is nonzero, then each time
       that an armed timer expires, the timer is reloaded from the value
       specified in new_value->it_interval".

Comment: "Expiring" means that the timer is finished and the handler is called, not that it is disabled completely. They use the word "disarm" for that.

Answer (score 1):

> `/* I don't know why this setting works. */
>   struct itimerspec it = {
>      .it_interval.tv_nsec = Cycle,
>      .it_value.tv_nsec = Cycle
>   };`
>
> ....
>   *[A]ccording to my understanding it should cause expiring of timer after one time.*

Setting `it_interval` arms the timer for intervalic, recurring expiry after the first expiry (scheduled by `it_value`).  That's why you see repeated invocations.